# NodeJS mysql2 - should I handle pool disconnections?

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling, pool, mysql2

I use mysql2 module in my NodeJS project.
I understand the concept of database pooling in mysql2 module
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).

Before using pool, I used regular connection with mysql2.createConnection() function,
but after some time I got **'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'** error.

My code is:
**db.js:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'sql server',
    user: 'username',
    database: 'database',
    password: 'pass',
    port: 3306,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
});
module.exports = pool;
```

And how I using it:

```
const db = require('db');
db.query(...);
```

The query() and execute() functions on pool instance automatically call release() function of pool instance, and that is very good (because I don't need to write that command manually after any query).

But I need to understand: if I work like that (with pool, instead of without pool), there is a guarentee
**'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'** will not be thrown? Should I handle that or the pooling mechanism does it automatically?

I ask because I saw on the internet some code that, for example, re-create the connection.
With pool, I need to re-create the connection sometime?

Thanks a lot!